# Google Chrome empty Finder window

Tags: finder, bug, google, malware

Today without (yet) no evident change in my working Mac running Mountain Lion (10.8.5) I saw at least 10 times an empty window pop up on top of my working environnment.[image: Google Chrome empty window].

At each of these events, I noticed that the window in which I was typing lost the focus and consequently what I was typing.

After a few quick investigation I found that this empty window is a Finder window and is clearly related to error messages within:

```
~/Library/Logs/GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent.log
```

as this typical one:

```
2014-09-25 12:16:23.302 GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent[24197/0xb0289000] [lvl=3] KSDiskImageHDIUtilRun() KSDiskImage hdiutil execution (status: 1): "/tmp/KSDownloadAction.sQtnQHG3Yu/com.google.Chrome.dmg"
        STDOUT:

        STDERR:
                hdiutil: attach failed - no mountable file systems
```

I don't use the Chrome web browser.

I installed it one year ago to test it from time to time.

I didn't use it recently.

---

What may be causing these Google Chrome empty Finder windows?

Did someone noticed the same spyware-like behaviour?

Does someone see any way to investigate this suspicious behaviour?

Comment: That window that you've taken a screen shot of, is a disk image.  Somehow the disk image of the Chrome installer is being opened.  You could probably resolve the issue simply by finding and deleting the .dmg file.  (Of course this won't uninstall GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent however)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way I removed this automatic upgrade which never explained me
what was going on.

The best information I found about this automatic update, and its removal is here:
[how to remove Google’s secret update software from your mac](http://applehelpwriter.com/2014/07/13/how-to-remove-googles-secret-update-software-from-your-mac/).

### Check the presence of GoogleSoftwareUpdate

```
defaults read com.google.Keystone.Agent
```

gives a lot of info confirming me that the `GoogleSoftwareUpdate` is active and configured.

### Stop the agent

```
cd /Library/LaunchAgents
launchctl unload com.google.keystone.agent.plist
```

### Uninstall GoogleSoftwareUpdate

```
cd ~/Library/Google
python GoogleSoftwareUpdate/GoogleSoftwareUpdate.bundle/Contents/Resources/GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent.app/Contents/Resources/install.py --uninstall

defaults read com.google.Keystone.Agent
```

outputs:

```
Domain com.google.Keystone.Agent does not exist
```

which confirms that the `GoogleSoftwareUpdate` doesn't have any more
any default configured.

### Clean up

```
cd ~/Library/Google
rm -rf GoogleSoftwareUpdate

cd ~/Library/Logs
rm GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent.log

cd /Library/LaunchAgents
/usr/bin/sudo rm com.google.keystone.agent.plist

cd /Library/Google
/usr/bin/sudo rm -rf GoogleSoftwareUpdate
```